# Why is my gf seeing a localhost self signed certificate when going to netflix?

Tags: certificates

Recently my gf told me she was receiving errors when trying to go to netflix. I took a look and the certificate is super wierd saying it is self signed. Why could this be happening? She only uses the computer on our home wifi. She does not know how to self sign certificates so there is no way she did that herself either. I can't for the life of me figure out the reason that is showing up and I'm concerned because that is a pretty bizarre thing to see... I don't know if she has been MITM but I don't see how that is possible when she is trying to access netflix through our home network. Our home network is a 15 character password. What are some reason's this could be happening and what can I do to investigate this?

See below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Has anyone had access to your router or computer who might have made modifications?

Comment: No one has had access to our house, let alone our router or computer.

Comment: Is it just her computer or is it anyone on your network? Does it happen for other HTTPS sites? There are some live router compromises floating about but it's far more likely to be malware on your GF's computer.

Comment: Yea I was assuming it would be malware. Doesn't happen on any other site that we've noticed. Just her computer. My computer, also on the network, is not having any problems with netflix

Comment: I ran a full system scan with MalwareBytes and Bitdefender. No viruses or malware found. Still pretty confused how this is happening...

Comment: After looking into her dns server settings I saw an entry for 80.82.77.166. I have no idea what that is but that is what the issue was. Removing that and putting in 1.1.1.1 solved the issue. Why would that entry be there? Is there a way to determine what that IP refers to?

Comment: @TerenceChow Well that would make sense. You're either using a malicious or otherwise oddly-behaving DNS server. It must have redirected your lookup to Netflix to a site that's performing MITM attacks. Maybe someone with more time can check that DNS server and see what it's really doing.

Comment: 80.82.77.166 is registered out of the Seychelles, but the server appears to be physically located in the Netherlands.